# php remove dot dot slash from all href and src

Tags: php

I'm making a html template that requires reletive links but for templeting i must use php (very noob), in the index file i'd like to remove all `../` from href an src, like this exemple:

```
page.php
scr="../img/image.jpg"
href="../contact/contact.php"

index.php
scr="img/image.jpg"
href="contact/contact.php"
```

How can I create a function to remove all `../`

Thanks

Comment: Can you not use a text editor to do that? They all have search and replace and most of them can do it on a set of files.. or am I missing something?

Comment: As Ben pointed out, find and replace in a text editor will do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the template in using get_file_contents then replace the string:

```
$sContents = file_get_contents('<URL TO FILE>');
$sContents = str_replace('../', '', $sContents);
```

Comment: Hi, i tried like this: `<?php
$sContents = file_get_contents('index.php');
$sContents = str_replace('../', '', $sContents);
?>
<a href="../teste">teste</a>
<?php require '_includes/header.php'; ?>

<h1>This is the index.php page</h1>` But not remove  `../` sorry I don't knok make a brake :(

Comment: The <URL TO FILE> needs to contain the template you have (pref in an .html page). The PHP should sit on a separate PHP page.

Answer (score 2):

If it's really so that the `../` is present just once at the beginning the following will work:

```
echo str_replace('../', $string);
```

if it could be that there is a presence of `../` in the middle of the path which should not being removed use `preg_replace()`:

```
$str = '../img/image.jpg';
echo preg_replace('~^(\.\./)(.*)$~', "$2", $str);
```

Comment: but then how do you save and/or run the resulting string.. we're looking at search/replace in a php file here.. yes?

Comment: As far as I understood the OP want's to output these links in a template